# NuGet Package Restore Not Working

Tags: nuget

I checked in a project on one computer, checked out on another, and find that the binaries installed by NuGet are missing.  I could check them in to source control as well, but it looks like there's a better solution:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

I followed those instructions, now have a `.nuget` folder where one should be, have the following entries in my .csproj file:

```
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

and yet when I rebuild my solution, the missing packages are not restored.

What am I missing?  How can I diagnose this problem?

Comment: Do you see nuget.exe being triggered in the Output log?

Comment: And importantly: are you seeing any errors in the Output log?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Note you can force package restore to execute by running the following commands in the nuget package manager console

> Update-Package -Reinstall

Forces re-installation of everything in the solution.

---

> Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName myProj

Forces re-installation of everything in the myProj project.

**Note**: This is the nuclear option. When using this command you may not get the same versions of the packages you have installed and that could be lead to issues. This is less likely to occur at a project level as opposed to the solution level.

You can use the `-safe` commandline parameter option to constrain upgrades to newer versions with the same Major and Minor version component. This option was added later and resolves some of the issues mentioned in the comments.

> Update-Package -Reinstall -Safe

Comment: Just be aware that running a reinstall on a solution can take a long time, you'll need to answer questions on file replacements and it had a bug/conflict with Git source control for me.

Comment: Not a good solution - this broke my project so it wouldn't run anymore.

Comment: @NightOwl888 that sounds like something that needs reported to nuget as there should be no way it could do that, unless perhaps you actually always had DLL hell binding issues and by luck it was working, but reinstalling it ended your luck of it working.

Comment: This command broke my project as it corrupted the web.config with new unwanted connectionString, completely blew away my existing membership, role provider config, and added other extraneous stuff. I don't know what other horrors await me. @NightOwl888

Comment: @nightowl if you're using source control it shouldn't be that hard to back the changes out.

Comment: The main draw back here is that package versions aren't maintained, so the latest package version will be installed. This can be a problem if your project is not compatible with a new version..

Comment: Yeah, the Update-Package -Reinstall worked for me.  I have no idea why the IDE just doesn't do it.  Everything is set correctly.  Ugghh, I swear, NuGet is both good and annoying.

Comment: Has anyone discovered whether this is a bug in NuGet or within certain packages or something?  I'm working on automating builds and I feel that I shouldn't have to add an "Update-Package -Reinstall" to my build script.  I'd like to be able to complain somewhere and feel well informed :)

Comment: I am using vs2015 and I found the packages\repositories.config file had old references to project repos I no longer used and thus removed them. Then a VS restart and surprisingly the error is at bay, for now.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you have opened up a project in VS 2012 and you do not have a solution file you will also get this error. In this case save the solution file and rebuild, the missing packages will then reinstall

Comment: @Abel great update. Don't know when they added that, but very useful to be included.

Comment: The following procedure is without risk: Delete the whole content of the _packages_ folder, and either a) use the _Restore NuGet Packages_ menu on the solution item, or b) in Tools | Options | NuGet Package Manager: Activate _Allow NuGet to download missing packages_ and _Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio_, and build the solution.

Comment: nice of you to add the "important! this could destroy your project" at the BOTTOM of your answer!

Comment: It doesn't install only one package named "Sustainsys.Saml2.MVC". But I think this answer is still really useful especially when there are a lot of projects in the solution and each project has many packages.

Comment: I've got a problem now where nuget reinstall seems to not work, even after clearing the nuget cache.  It just says No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'XXXXX.vbproj'. For my 2 projects :(  Building causes the nuget cache to reload but something not right here, as several references to nuget packages are showing warning icons. Sigh

Comment: After issuing Update-package -reinstall, all projects is my solution are updated.  When I do a build, all projects fail with the error - This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\NBWExcelAddIn\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.2.9.6\build\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.props.

Comment: @DougKimzey you could try installing or updating package for NBWExcelAddIn to an earlier or later version and then build

Answer (score 31):

For others who stumble onto this post, read this.

NuGet 2.7+ introduced us to ***Automatic Package Restore***.  This is considered to be a much better approach for most applications as it does not tamper with the MSBuild process.  Less headaches.

**Some links to get you started:**

- [The right way to restore NuGet packages](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html)
- [Migrate away from MSBuild-based NuGet package restore](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore)
- [Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore)

Comment: Thank you for an answer appropriate to the current version of NuGet.

Answer (score 23):

You have to choose one way of the following :

Re-installing a package by it's name in all solution's projects:

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```

Re-installing a package by it's name and ignoring it's dependencies in all solution's projects:

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName> -ignoreDependencies
```

Re-installing a package by it's name in a project:

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName> <projectName>
```

Re-installing all packages in a specific project:

```
Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName <projectName>
```

Re-installing all packages in a solution:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Comment: Solved my problem quick-and-dirty style.

Comment: Can break projects because it may install a newer version of a package than what was specified.

Answer (score 21):

Did you enable package restore mode in the project that has the missing packages/binaries ? There's a known issue that requires the packages to be correctly installed when enabling the restore mode :

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1879

---

Original link is dead; this might be a replacement: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1968

Comment: Thanks for the link. Enable package restore mode in a project that has the missing packages/binaries will be a common case. If you don't have the packages, that's when you want to get them. Use-case fail.

Comment: When you say, "enable package restore mode in the project that has the missing packages", what do you mean?  Is there a console command that I need to run to do that?

Comment: @Jammer 10 years later, nuget still can't reliably restore packages.  We ended up creating some python scripts that ACTUALLY do it correctly.

Answer (score 18):

VS 2017

Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Settings>General
Click on "Clear All NuGet Cache(s)"

Comment: When checking a solution out of source control (managed using the Visual Studio Team Explorer with DevOps/Git) builds were not possible due to missing references and restore packages did nothing. This solution was the correct one for this circumstance.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem with testing local NuGet package!

Answer (score 11):

I have run into this problem in two scenarios.

First, when I attempt to build my solution from the command line using msbuild.exe. 
Secondly, when I attempt to build the sln and the containing projects on my build server using TFS and CI.

I get errors claiming that references are missing. When inspecting both my local build directory and the TFS server's I see that the /packages folder is not created, and the nuget packages are not copied over. Following the instructions listed in Alexandre's answer http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1879 also did not work for me.

I've enabled Restore Packages via VS2010 and I have seen builds only work from within VS2010. Again, using msbuild fails.My workaround is probably totally invalid, but for my environment this got everything working from a command line build locally, as well as from a CI build in TFS.

I went into .\nuget and changed this line in the .nuget\NuGet.targets file:

from:

```
<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)" -o "$(PackagesDir)"</RestoreCommand>
```

to: (notice, without the quotes around the variables)

```
<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install $(PackagesConfig) -source $(PackageSources) -o $(PackagesDir)</RestoreCommand>
```

I understand that if my directories have spaces in them, this will fail, but I don't have spaces in my directories and so this workaround got my builds to complete successfully...for the time being.

I will say that turning on diagnostic level logging in your build will help show what commands are being executed by msbuild. This is what led me to hacking the targets file temporarily.

Comment: I had the issue with the double quotes and had to make the same edit that you did. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 11):

If none of the other answers work for you then try the following which was the only thing that worked for me:

Find your `.csproj` file and edit it in a text editor.

Find the `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">` tag in your `.csproj` file and delete the whole block.

Re-install all packages in the solution:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

After this your nuget packages should be restored, i think this might be a fringe case that only occurs when you move your project to a different location.

Comment: This saved me from going completely nuts.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me out of many solutions. I sincerely thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If anything else didn't work, try:

1. Close Project.
2. Delete packages folder in your solution folder.
3. Open Project again and restore Nugget Packages again.

Worked for me and it's easy to try.

Comment: This worked for me.  In step 3, I did not have to manually restore the packages--they restored automatically when I opened the project.

Answer (score 4):

Just for others that might run into this problem, I was able to resolve the issue by closing Visual Studio and reopening the project. When the project was loaded the packages were restored during the initialization phase.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had an empty tag NuGetPackageImportStamp in .csproj

```xml
<NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
```

It should ideally contain some valid GUID.

Removing this tag and then "Restore Nugets" worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2017, right-click on the solution => Open CommandLine => Developer Command Line.

Once thats open, type in (and press enter after)

```
dotnet restore
```

That will restore any/all packages, and you get a nice console output of whats been done...

Answer (score 2):

None of the other solutions worked in my situation:

AspNetCore dependencies had been installed/uninstalled and were being cached. 'AspNetCore.All' would refuse to properly update/reinstall/remove. And regardless of what i did, it would use the cached dependencies (that it was not compatible with), because they were a higher version.

1. Backup Everything. Note the list of Dependencies you'll need to reinstall, Exit VisualStudio
2. Open up all .proj files in a text editor and remove all `PackageReference`
3. In each project, delete the `bin`, `obj` folders
4. Delete any "packages" folders you find in the solution.
5. Open solution, go into `Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager
   Settings` and `Clear all Nuget caches`. Check the console because it may
   fail to remove some items - copy the folder path and exit visual
   studio.
6. Delete anything from that folder Reopen solution and start
   installing nuget packages again from scratch.

If that still doesn't work, repeat but also search your drive in windows explorer for `nuget` and delete anything cachey looking.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes something strange happens and using Visual Studio to automatically restore doesn't work.  In that case you can use the NuGet Package Manager Console.  That is opened within Visual Studio from **Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console**.  The commands within the console are simple.  And to get context help while typing a command just press the  button and it will give you all options that start with the letters you're typing.  So if a package isn't installed, for example log4net, type the following command:

Install-Package log4net

You can do a whole lot more, like specify the version to install, update a package, uninstall a package, etc.

I had to use the console to help me when Visual Studio was acting like a weirdo.

Answer (score 1):

**Automatic Package Restore will fail for any of the following reasons:**

1. You did not remove the NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets files from the solution's .nuget folder (which can be found in your solution root folder)
2. You did not enable automatic package restore from the Tools >> Options >> Nuget Package Manager >> General settings.
3. You forgot to manually remove references in all your projects to the Nuget.targets file
4. You need to restart Visual Studio (make sure the process is killed from your task manager before starting up again).

The following article outlines in more detail how to go about points 1-3: 
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Comment: Regarding your #1 point, the link you provide contradicts your advice:
"If you are using TFS

 1. Remove the NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets files from the solution's
    .nuget folder 
 2. Retain the NuGet.Config file to continue to bypass adding packages to source control."

Answer (score 1):

I had NuGet packages breaking after I did a System Restore on my system, backing it up about two days.  (The NuGet packages had been installed in the meantime.)  To fix it, I had to go to the .nuget\packages folder in my user profile, find the packages, and delete them.  Only then would Visual Studio pull the packages down fresh and properly add them as references.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround that I found creating a new Project from scratch,
then import all the source files with the code.
My project was not so complicated so I had no problem from there.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem recently as well.  The usual 'dotnet restore' and 'Update-Package -reinstall' didn't help.

I looked at the .csproj file and found that the  values for these packages were inconsistent.  Some were pointing to `<solutiondir>\packages` and some were `<projectdir>\packages`.

I made them all point to the same place (I believe that was to `<projectdir>\packages`) and then I was able to restore the NuGet packages.

I'm not sure how the .csproj file ended up pointing to two different places.  Maybe from starting out in Visual Studio 2017 (or earlier) and then moving to Visual Studio 2019?  Or different settings used by different programmers?  I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

On VS 2022, the fix for me was weird, just had to open the "Nuget Package Manager", click the settings (gear icon), then uncheck all the package sources, click OK, then check them again and that's it.

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2022 when none of the other options were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

vs2015 no enable nuget restore problem.
My solution:

1. add folder .nuget, add file NuGet.Config and NuGet.targets  in Directory .nuget
2. each project file add:
   build

```
  <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>

  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: This is the old way of doing it. See @davenewza answer, and his link to http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

If the error you are facing is "unable to connect to remote server" as was mine, then it would benefit you to have this check as well in addition to the checks provided in the above comments.

I saw that there were 2 NUGET Package Sources from which the packages could be downloaded (within Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Packager Manager Settings). One of the Package Source's was not functioning and Nuget was trying to download from that source only.

**Things fell into place once I changed the package source to download from: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ EXPLICTLY in the settings**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an aborted Nuget restore-attempt had corrupted one of the `packages.config`files in the solution. I did not discover this before checking my git working tree. After reverting the changes in the file, Nuget restore was working again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut to make Nuget restore work.

1. Make sure internet connection or Nuget urls are proper in VS Tools options menu
2. Look at .nuget or nuget folder in the solution, else - copy from any to get nuget.exe
3. DELETE packages folders, if exists
4. Open the Package manager console execute this command

- paste full path of nuget.exe  RESTORE  full path of .sln file!

5. use Install-pacakge  command, if build did not get through for any missing references.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I encountered but what solved my problem was to go to Nuget Package Manager (rightclick to the prj > select Manage Nugget Packages) and uninstall and install again the packages that are having issues.

BUT there are some packages having dependencies to other packages, so what I did was to uninstall the dependencies first and then followed by the nuget package that I wanted to uninstall and re-install.

You can find out if the nuget has dependencies when you tried to uninstall it and then visit the Output window, there will be a line saying that the nuget failed to uninstall because of its dependencies, and those dependencies are also listed there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but it was the first search result today (in 2022) for "nuget package restore canceled". This is the message I got in VS when trying to rebuild a solution at my new job.

I've been in the new job for a few weeks and the build worked up to now.

The package source used by my solution is xxxxPackages, where xxxx is the name of my employer. So the package source is not nuget.org, which I normally use.
Occasionally, a message was appearing in VS saying:

"TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxxxdev.visualstudio.com."

Despite this, I had xxxxdev.visualstudio.com open in my browser and was able to work in it.

I tried many of the suggestions here. Then, chatting to a colleague, it turned out that my VS login had gone stale. In Visual Studio, I clicked on my icon in the top right and selected 'account settings'. There was an exclamation mark indicating that I had to refresh the login to my work account on visualstudio.com, using my xxxx email address.

Once I had done this the problem went away.
I hope this saves others the hassle I had this morning.

Answer (score 0):

In the EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports section of the csproj file, there should be Error xml and if all the conditions starts from ..\packages modify that to where the packages are. In my case the packages were in the same level as the solution so I had to remove ..\ and start with packages\ and it worked afterwards. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in my case , I go to Tools ->Nuget Package Manger ->source
and I removed all sources
the i added https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json as source
this fixed the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).