# Nuget can't build dependency graph, so can't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have package called KendoUIProfessional.  When I try to uninstall it, I get the following error:

```
uniNStall-package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. 
Restore the packages before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:1
+ uniNStall-package kendouiprofessional -force -verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UninstallPackageCommand
```

I get a similar error when I try to install the package. I also get the error:
    An error occurred while trying to restore packagesL Unable to find version '2014.2.716 of package 'KendiUIProfessional'.

When I try to do anything else with NuGet, I get the message that Kendo can't be found.

This all started with my upgrade to Visual Studio 2015...

Comment: Did you try this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011889/nuget-package-restore-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
1) Delete the packages folder
2) Manually delete the assemblies
3) Uninstall/Reinstall nuget package