# "Restore NuGet Packages" in Visual Studios 2015 not doing anything

Tags: c#, svn, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I pulled my solution from SVN into Visual Studios 2015. I'm getting errors on some of my "using" references within the code, so I am trying to run the "Restore NuGet Packages" option when right clicking the solution in the "Solution Explorer". This does nothing. I have to manually go into nuget manager and uninstall then reinstall the items. Why is this? How can I get "Restore NuGet Packages" to work?

Answer (score 5):

> You might did not enabled automatic package restore from the following section:

**Tools >> Options >> Nuget Package Manager >> General settings.**

Also you can try this:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

This code will forces re-installation in all solution's projects.

Look at the following for more info:

[nuget-package-restore-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011889/nuget-package-restore-not-working)

[Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore)

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

1. Download the project from TFS (or in your case SVN).
2. Delete the "packages" folder
3. Make sure the "Package Manager Console" is enabled (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)
4. Open the solution file.
5. At the right side of the "Package Manager Console," a "Restore" button should appear. Click on the "Restore" button.

After following those steps, I no longer get those errors with the "using" references after building.

Hope that helps you.

Edit:
If after you complete the above steps you are still getting syntax errors from missing references, right-click on References in the Solution Explorer and then just hit OK. That fixed the problem with the references for me.