# "Could not restore packages" in Visual Studio code when opening a project

Tags: c#, package, visual-studio-mac

After each update of MacOS or Visual Studio any project I open throws this error and can't restore packages. It happens in Visual Studio for Mac, the latest version.

Screenshot of the package console

[image: 1]

Once I had a similar issue when a vpm connection was active, after disabling it Visual Studio had no issues with packages. But this time I don't have any VPN enabled.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac's IDE log may have more information, this is available from the Help menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who is interested, I found a solution to this issue.

1. Execute this command in terminal for the project `dotnet nuget locals --clear all`
2. While the project(solution) is opened in the Visual Studio, double-click on the top file (Solution) > Build > General > check the **Build with MSBuild on Mono** option.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft suggests the following if restore is not working:

> 1. Select the Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings menu command.
> 2. Set both options under Package Restore.
> 3. Select OK.
> 4. Build your project again.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting

Another suggestion:

> Try deleting the project.assets.json file in the obj folder of your project and then right click on the solution and click Restore NuGet Packages again.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/restore-nuget-packages-is-not-working/1367227

If those don't work here are other overflow suggestions:
[NuGet Package Restore Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011889/nuget-package-restore-not-working)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've seen this suggestion on the Microsoft's site. 

1. Checkbox were already present.
2. I don't have this file

Comment: Did the restructure of your packages change or folder too deeply nested? That can also affect things too.

Comment: Last maybe helpful link I have https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3324#issuecomment-977921700

Comment: >Did the restructure of your packages change or folder too deeply nested? That can also affect things too.

There are two packages only, no deep nesting. Just a few small classes

Comment: >Last maybe helpful link I have github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3324#issuecomment-977921700

this doesn't help